# c# unit testing, mocking stored procedure

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stored-procedures, mocking, system.data

In the past when I have been implementing unit test I have struggled to set up 'decent' unit tests for data access layers because they often have a database as an external dependency.  In an ideal world I would mock the stored procedure calls so that the external dependency is removed.

However I have been unable to work out how to do this with the MOQ mocking framework, or find any other framework which supports this.  Instead I have reverted to creating a scripted test database with known data in (so that I can always get outputs I expect) but this is slightly different from Mocking that layer.

Can anyone suggest how to Mock this part of the data access layer [I know for Entity Framework that https://effort.codeplex.com/ exists]?

---

**Detail**
For instance if I have the following method

```
public object RunStoredProc()
{
    //Some Setup

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNNECTION_STRING))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("storedProcName", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //Logic
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Return object based on logic
}
```

then how do I mock the stored procedure output so that `SQLDataReader` contains specified data.  At a higher level I could mock the `RunStoredProc()` method - but that won't help me test whether the logic in that method is correct.  Alternatively I could strip the `SQLReader` out into another method

```
public object RunStoredProc()
{
    //Some Setup

    List<object> data = GetData();
    //Logic

    //Return object based on logic
}

private List<object> GetData()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNNECTION_STRING))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("storedProcName", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //place into return object
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but as the 'GetData' method should be private (not part of the published interface) I then wouldn't be able to mock that and so the issue remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we have all the interfaces (`IDbConnection`, `IDbTransaction`, `IDbCommand`, `IDataReader`) and borrowing an idea from EF (`IDbConnectionFactory`) to abstract everything needed so that they can be mocked and used with Dependency Injection. I think `SqlConnection` and the rest are more of an implementation detail and can be abstracted.

Following an idea from Entity Framework you can create a connection factory

```
public interface IDbConnectionFactory {
    /// <summary>
    ///  Creates a connection based on the given database name or connection string.
    IDbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString);
}
```

And you can then refactor your example method to use only the abstractions.

```
public class MyDataAccessClass {
    private IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory;
    private string CONNNECTION_STRING = "Connection string here";

    public MyDataAccessClass(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory) {
        this.dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
    }

    public object RunStoredProc() {
        //Some Setup
        List<object> result = new List<object>();

        using (IDbConnection conn = dbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(CONNNECTION_STRING)) {
            using (IDbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand()) {
                comm.CommandText = "storedProcName";
                conn.Open();
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (IDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        //...Logic to populate result
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Return object based on logic
        return result;
    }
}
```

From there you mock the interfaces using your mocking framework of choice or create your own fakes to inject and test your method.

```
[TestClass]
public class StoredProcedureUnitTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRunStoredProc() {
        //Arrange
        var connectionFactory = new Mock<IDbConnectionFactory>();
        //..Setup...

        var sut = new MyDataAccessClass(connectionFactory.Object);

        //Act
        var actual = sut.RunStoredProc();

        //Assert
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, looks like it'll work, if I'm reading this correctly the only method I'd need to mock would be IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() [I'd also need to mock IDbConnection.CreatCommand to return the mocked IDbCommand but that should be trivial].  I'm going to leave the question open for a while in case anyone else has any other ideas.